# How to return my "theMove" and solve the writing rights problem

Tags: c, typedef

I am trying to do a chessboard with movements, and I cannot manage to get the coordinates of the 2 chess pieces to move:

```
void saisie_deplacement(int color)
{
    char lettre[8]={'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'};
    deplacement theMove;

    char L,L1;
    int x,x1,y,y1;

    printf("\n\n\nType the 1st piece's Letter.\n");
    scanf(" %c", &L);

    x = L;
    x = x-'A';
    printf("\n%i\n", x);

    printf("\nType the 1st piece figure\n");
    scanf(" %i", &y);

    printf("\nType the 2nd piece letter\n");
    scanf(" %c", &L1);

    x1= L1;
    x1=x1 - 'A';
    printf("\n%i\n", x1);

    printf("\n\n\nType the 2nd piece figure\n");
    scanf(" %i", &y1);

    theMove.depart.ligne = x;
    theMove.depart.colonne = y;
    theMove.arrivee.ligne = x1;
    theMove.arrivee.colonne = y1;

}
```

I don't know how I can return `theMove`.

Otherwise, CodeBlocks tells me this :

```
||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
ld.exe||cannot open output file C:\Users\dissi\Desktop\C\tpregled.exe Permission denied|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Then i can't compile without changing the .exe file name. It seems like my program stays open in ntoskrnl.exe

Would you guys know what i should do about it ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return `theMove`, do as follows:

First declare that the function will return it:

```
deplacement saisie_deplacement(int color) {
```

(`void` means it will return nothing, but you do want it to return something of type `deplacement`)

Then after having filled in all the fields, tell the function to return the variable of type `deplacement`:

```
    return theMove;
}
```

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Thanks a lot for your answer, tried it out and it seems to work !
However i still have the writing problem, any idea ?

Comment: @dissi what is the writing problem? The `ld returned 1 exit status`? That's due to the fact that your application did not finish its execution. You probably have a never-ending loop or a scanf preventing your application to be terminated. But it is impossible to say it since your main application has not been provided. BTW: it would be a different question (that probably already has many answers on this site), so consider accpting the answer if it was helpful for you.